# Python TypeError float is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

Here is a short program which is giving me an error I'm having a difficult time understanding:

```
import time
TIMEOUT_LENGTH = 0.4
TIMEOUT_CHECK = False
STOPPED = True
timeout = 0.0

def start_timer():
    global timeout
    global STOPPED
    global TIMEOUT_CHECK

    TIMEOUT_CHECK = False
    STOPPED = False
    timeout = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH

def stop_timer():
    global STOPPED
    global TIMEOUT_CHECK

    TIMEOUT_CHECK = False
    STOPPED = True

def timeout():   
    global timeout
    global STOPPED
    global TIMEOUT_CHECK

    currTime = time.time()
    if (currTime > timeout) and (STOPPED == False):
       TIMEOUT_CHECK = True
    return TIMEOUT_CHECK

start_timer()
print timeout()
```

Running this gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prob.py", line 34, in <module>
    print timeout()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

It doesn't look to me as if I'm trying to call `currTime` or `timeout`. What is going on here that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I am such a fool. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: It's exactly the silly mistakes like this that are impossible to spot yourself and easy for others to spot.

Comment: I appreciate that you gave this question a title that is easy to search for so that future users will be able to reference this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have both a function *and* another variable named `timeout`. Rename one or the other.

As it stands, you first bind `timeout` to a float value `0.0`. You then *rebind* it by defining a `timeout()` function. Last but not least, by calling `start_timer()` you rebind `timeout` *again*, back to a float number:

By the time you try to execute `print timeout()`, `timeout` is bound to a floating point value and not a function anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You make a function named `timeout`, but then you override that and make `timeout` a float here:

```
timeout = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH
```

You need to either change the name of the function or the name of the float.  They both can't be named `timeout`.

Comment: It's not a string, it's a float (`time()` returns a number, and he's adding `0.4` to it—plus, look at the exception text). But otherwise, nice explanation.

Comment: @abarnert - Whoa, that was dumb.  Fixed it. :)